# SwiftUI rotate together with addArc doesn't work correctly in some cases

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, swiftui

Swift 5, iOS 13

Using addArc to draw a semi-circle and then using rotation3DEffect to rotate it. On the y axis it works perfectly, but in the x axis is seems broken. Am I doing something wrong here.

I got this code to work. But it is a kludge.

I want to us the x axis on the MyArc2 and not have to use an offset+rotationEffect. The first image is what you see with this code as is.

However if I do use x axis it doesn't draw it correctly.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var turn:Double = 0
  var body: some View {
    return VStack {
    Image(systemName: "circle")
      .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
      .onTapGesture {
        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 36)) {
          self.turn = 360
       }
     }
     Globe2View(turn: $turn)
    } // VStack
  }
 }

 struct Globe2View: View {
  struct MyArc : Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    var p = Path()
    p.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.screenWidth/2, y:UIScreen.screenHeight/2), radius: 64, startAngle: .degrees(90), endAngle: .degrees(270), clockwise: true)
    return p
}
}
   struct MyArc2 : Shape {
   func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    var p = Path()
    p.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.screenWidth/2, y:UIScreen.screenHeight/2), radius: 64, startAngle: .degrees(90), endAngle: .degrees(270), clockwise: true)
  return p
  }
  }
  @Binding var turn:Double
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
     ForEach(0..<12) { loop in
      MyArc()
        .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 2)
        .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.turn + Double((loop * 30))), axis: (x: 0, y: -1, z: 0), anchor: UnitPoint.center, anchorZ: 0, perspective: 0)
  }
      ForEach(0..<12) { loop in
       MyArc2()
         .stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: 2)
        .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.turn + Double((loop * 30))), axis: (x: 0, y: -1, z: 0), anchor: UnitPoint.center, anchorZ: 0, perspective: 0)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(90))
        .offset(x: 20, y: 20)
    }
  }
 }
}
```

[image]

If I change the last few lines so they look like this...

```
struct MyArc2 : Shape {
func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    var p = Path()
    p.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.screenWidth/2, y:UIScreen.screenHeight/2), radius: 64, startAngle: .degrees(0), endAngle: .degrees(180), clockwise: true)
  return p
}
}

 ForEach(0..<12) { loop in
    MyArc2()
      .stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: 2)
      .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.turn + Double((loop * 30))), axis: (x: 1, y: 0, z: 0), anchor: UnitPoint.center, anchorZ: 0, perspective: 0)
//          .rotationEffect(.degrees(90))
//          .offset(x: 20, y: 20)
   }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear why it is needed `MyArc2` as it is the same, but the following, with simple fix in shape, just works as expected (to my mind).

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```
struct Globe2View: View {
    struct MyArc : Shape {
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            var p = Path()
            // used provided dynamic rect instead of hardcoded NSScreen
            p.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.width/2, y:rect.height/2), radius: 64, startAngle: .degrees(90), endAngle: .degrees(270), clockwise: true)
            return p
        }
    }

    @Binding var turn:Double
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(0..<12) { loop in
                MyArc()
                    .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 2)
                    .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.turn + Double((loop * 30))), axis: (x: 0, y: -1, z: 0), anchor: UnitPoint.center, anchorZ: 0, perspective: 0)
            }
            ForEach(0..<12) { loop in
                MyArc()
                    .stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: 2)
                    .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.turn + Double((loop * 30))), axis: (x: 0, y: -1, z: 0), anchor: UnitPoint.center, anchorZ: 0, perspective: 0)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(90))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what change in shape, you mean using MyArc and not MyArc2. If they are identical then why doesn^t the other version work?